Как запускать скрипт при открытии книги или активации листа Google Sheet?
Есть вариант запускать  скрипт при  открытии файла или активации  листа Google sheet по аналогии с Excel VBA?
Что-то типа
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
...
End Sub
или
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
...
End Sub

Да, есть различные события, которые могут запускать определенные функции Google Apps Script.
Есть пара видов таких функций (простые и устанавливаемые)
Например, аналог Private Sub Workbook_Open() - это функция onOpen(e)
